# Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'Text'

Tags: flutter, dart

What is the best way of formatting text enclosed in MdiIcons in flutter and set the text to a particular color in my case white?

Doing it this way I end up with the text appearing as color black(default set by flutter and I want it that way):

```
[MdiIcons.shieldAccount, Colors.deepPurple, 'COVID-19 Info Center'],
```

Doing it this way I end up with an error

```
 [MdiIcons.shieldAccount, Colors.deepPurple, Text('COVID-19 Info Center', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),)]
```

the error being thrown is

> Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'Text'

The code

```
class MoreOptionsList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<List> _moreOptionsList = const [
    [MdiIcons.shieldAccount, Colors.deepPurple, Text('COVID-19 Info Center', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),)],
    [MdiIcons.accountMultiple, Colors.cyan, Text('Friends', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),)],
    [MdiIcons.facebookMessenger, Colors.pinkAccent, Text('Messenger', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),)],
    [MdiIcons.flag, Colors.orange, Text('Pages', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),)],
    [MdiIcons.storefront, Colors.lightBlue, Text('Market Place', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),)],
    [MdiIcons.video, Colors.green, Text('Events', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),)],
  ];
  final User currentUser;

  const MoreOptionsList({Key key,
    @required this.currentUser}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 280.0),
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 1 +  _moreOptionsList.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
          if(index == 0) {
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
              child: UserCard(user: currentUser),
            );
          }
          final List option = _moreOptionsList [index-1];
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
            child: _Option(icon: option[0], color: option[1], label: option[2]),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _Option extends StatelessWidget {
  final IconData icon;
  final Color color;
  final String label;

  const _Option({Key key,
    @required this.icon,
    @required this.color,
    @required this.label}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () => print(label),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Icon(icon, size:38.0, color: color,),
          const SizedBox(width: 6.0),
          Flexible(child: Text(
            label, style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ),)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Text` is a `widget` not a string you should color the text inside the widget that required the string so that is mean you can't use widget for string

Comment: how should i write it?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get the widget from the list you should change the label type to `Text` or `Widget` instead of using String type like this

```
class _Option extends StatelessWidget {
  final IconData icon;
  final Color color;
  final Text label;

  const _Option({Key key,
    @required this.icon,
    @required this.color,
    @required this.label}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () => print(label),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Icon(icon, size:38.0, color: color,),
          const SizedBox(width: 6.0),
          Flexible(child: label)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

if the above code didn't help or wasn't good enough you can use this one by adding the String to list then adding it to the Text `don't forget to restart the app`

```
  final List<List> _moreOptionsList = const [
    [Icons.ac_unit, Colors.deepPurple, 'COVID-19 Info Center'],
    [Icons.ac_unit, Colors.cyan, 'Friends'],
    [Icons.ac_unit, Colors.pinkAccent, 'Messenger'],
    [Icons.ac_unit, Colors.orange, 'Pages'],
    [Icons.ac_unit, Colors.lightBlue, 'Market Place'],
    [Icons.ac_unit, Colors.green, 'Events'],
  ];
class _Option extends StatelessWidget {
  final IconData icon;
  final Color color;
  final String label;

  const _Option(
      {Key key,
      @required this.icon,
      @required this.color,
      @required this.label})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () => print(label),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Icon(
            icon,
            size: 38.0,
            color: color,
          ),
          const SizedBox(width: 6.0),
          Flexible(
            child: Text(
              '$label',
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.black),
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```